# How to dispose of NotifyIcon, after the timeout has occured (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a NotifyIcon method, although I would like the timeout to happen, before disposing of the BaloonTip.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
    <wait until timeout occurs>
    notifyIcon1.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: Is the question here how to wait for a timeout, or is it that your balloon gets hidden to soon?

Comment: @Jan-Peter Vos How to do a timeout

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` will block your UI until the timeout is over, The answer of @Hertzel Guinness would be a lot better. Is there any reason you'd want to dispose the `NotifyIcon`? What do you want the code to do if the user clicks the button again 10 seconds later?

Answer (score 3):

```
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipClosed += delegate {notifyIcon1.Dispose ();};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather hide the `NotifyIcon` instead of recreating/disposing a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timer.
Should be something like...:

```
private Timer taskTimer;
private NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
    taskTimer = new Timer(TimerCallback, notifyIcon1, 30000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

and...

```
void TimerCallback(object notifyIcon1Obj)
{
    lock (notifyIcon1Obj) 
    {
        NotifyIcon notifyIcon1 = (NotifyIcon)notifyIcon1Obj;
        notifyIcon1.dispose();
        notifyIcon1 = null;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Wrong kind of timer.  You cannot dispose controls on a threadpool thread.  It won't compile either.  Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.